# Panasonic Bath Exaust Fan Wiring. 7 wires and a ground?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, exhaust-fan

Based on this diagram I am thinking I need to run a Romex 12/4 and a 12/2 from a four gang box (4 switches?) Am I reading it wrong? What is the fourth switch for? I’m hoping to have only 3 switches - one for the light, one for the nightlight, and one for the fan. Panasonic WhisperThin DC LED Pick-A-Flow 80-100 CFM Model # RG-T810LA Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Panasonic WhisperThin DC LED Pick-A-Flow 80-100 CFM Model # RG-T810LA

Comment: https://ftp.panasonic.com/ventilationfan/servicemanual/rg-t810la_sm.pdf

Answer (score 4):

This fan has two speed settings.  The idea is to run continuously at low speed to ventilate multiple rooms and at high speed as needed for eg toilet or kitchen use.

The fan's black/white connection supplies power for both speeds.  The red/red one activates high speed.

Switches inside the fan control what the two speeds actually are.

You don't *have* to provide wall switches for all functions.  If you do, instead of a /4 you can use a /3 for the lights, a /2 for the fan as it has its own neutral and a /2 for the red loop.

The internal speed knobs are set according to room volume, occupancy and vent size.  The manual guides you.

[Added: Here are some specific ways to reduce the gangs or cables]

- If you just don't want a big 4-gang switch bay, buy two duplex switches.  Then you get full control in a two-gang box.  You could buy one duplex switch with horizontal rockers for the fan and another with vertical ones for the lights for nice tactile feedback on switching the right switch.
- If you don't want to use conduit and want to reduce the amount of cable, you could forgo the low-speed-always-on function.  Just connect the two red wires to each other in the fan, and when the fan is switched on it will run at its high speed.  You can use a /4 (sharing a neutral between the fan and lights) or a /3 for the lights and /2 for the fan.  You could then buy a triplex switch designed for this specific purpose, with a one-gang front, one horizontal and two smaller vertical rockers.  With a one gang device if you use two cables you should use a bigger box and a one-gang mud ring.
- If you're going to do the latter, eliminate the low-speed function, you could exchange this fan for a cheaper model that doesn't have all those functions.

Comment: That’s what I was hoping that I don’t have to provide switches for all functions. Thank you.

Comment: I added suggestions to the answer on how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

I pulled up the manual for that fan and it only shows three switches.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I don’t know why i couldn’t find that manual. Could you send a link?

Comment: @ACS https://ftp.panasonic.com/ventilationfan/servicemanual/rg-t810la_sm.pdf https://ftp.panasonic.com/ventilationfan/installation/rg-t810la_eng.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Aside from not exactly matching the wiring (number of switches, etc.) the manual image in the question references "Netural" instead of "Neutral". That type of error is common for non-certified junk made by anonymous manufacturers in certain very large Asian countries. But Panasonic is a reputable company and knows how to build things - and document them - correctly. The installation manual is available online. I found it on [Home Depot](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/d5/d5688104-4d4c-4527-8654-33350affd677.pdf), but it should be available directly from Panasonic.

- Black (switched fan hot) and white (neutral) from fan to one switch.
- Black (switched light hot), blue (switched nightlight hot) and white (neutral) to a pair of switches. Because of the shared neutral, these three wires *must* be together in one cable or conduit.
- Green ground

Your cable choices are:

- 12/4 - 4-wire cable (plus ground) - black/red/blue/white. Connect cable black to one black, red to the other black, blue to blue, cable white to *both* whites.
- 12/3 + 12/2 - 12/3 black/red/white for light/night light (black to black, red to blue, white to white) and 12/2 for fan.

All grounds always together.

I find it interesting that selection of fan speed is an installation option and not something you can switch during use. Which means it is lets a retailer stock and a a builder install one item for small or large bathrooms. But it doesn't give you (the consumer) the option to adjust speed on the fly like you typically can with a ceiling fan or a kitchen exhaust fan. If you want that flexibility then you'll need a different unit.

Comment: That clears up a lot. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, Panasonic manuals **are** full of typos. Go figure. And just to add, some people don't hook up the night light. That'll save a wire if you go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I put one of these on my bench and powered it up.  One black wire is for the fan, one for the bright light.  The blue wire is for the night light.  Connecting or disconnecting the red wires together has no effect on fan speed.  Instead fan speed is controlled by a little switch under the cover.  What does the humidity sensor do?  They don't say, but I assume it turns off the fan if the humidity is low.

Comment: I'm conflicted. You seem to have provided a reasonable answer, then you went off the rails and asked a question. I'd suggest you [edit] this answer to remove the question part, and, if you want someone to actually answer that question, please feel free to [ask a whole new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Also, take the [tour] to see how things work a bit differently around here.